# Firebase Analytics error regarding Analytics Screen Reporting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Previously, I had set up an iOS app with Firebase and received the following error:

"Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged."

I added FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED to Info.plist and set this boolean value to "YES". However, I noticed I had set the value of FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled in Info.plist to NO. Thus, I changed it to YES and am now getting a new message as shown below:

Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name.

Is this an error message or not an error? What is the action I should take here. From a big picture I am trying to set up a reference to an image I have uploaded to Firebase Console.

Comment: Not writing all caps in the question would be a start.

Comment: I have updated the title. I had written it that way with the intent of being specific to what the issue is

Comment: Yeah I know what your intent was. Thanks for updating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SWIFT**

Try setting this code in your AppDelegate.swift file.

```
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.analyticsConfiguration.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

and you can edit the firebase "logger level" to maximum with this line

```
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.max)
```

**OBJ-C**

```
[[FIRAnalyticsConfiguration sharedInstance] setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:YES];
[[FIRConfiguration sharedInstance] setLoggerLevel:FIRLoggerLevelMax];
```